# Proving that $\lim_{z\to z_0}z^2+c=z_0^2+c$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am teaching myself complex analysis and after learning about epsilon-delta limits, I saw an exercise that asked to prove that

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}z^2+c=z_0^2+c$$

I would like to know if this approach is correct, since there are no answers in the textbook, and this approach isn’t showcased in any supplementary examples:

Prove that

$$f(z)=z^2+c \Rightarrow |f(z)-(z_0^2+c)|=|z^2+c-(z_0^2+c)|=|z^2-z_0^2|=|(z-z_0)(z+z_0)|=|z-z_0||z+z_0|$$

So if for some $\epsilon>0$ and $0<|z-z_0|<\frac{\epsilon}{|z+z_0|}$, then $|f(z)-(z_0^2+c)|<\epsilon$. Thus, the limit definition is satisfied, taking $\delta$ to be $\frac{\epsilon}{|z+z_0|}$.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Note $\delta$ can only depend on $z_0$ and $\epsilon$, and **not** on $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make $\delta$ dependent on $z$. Use the fact that $|z-z_0||z+z_0| \leq |z-z_0|(|z-z_0|+2|z_0|) <|z-z_0|(|1+2|z_0|)<\epsilon$ if $|z-z_0| <1$ and $|z-z_0| <\frac {\epsilon} {1+2|z_0|} $. So we can take $\delta =\min \{1, \frac {\epsilon} {1+2|z_0|} \}$.

Comment: Thank you! Why can’t it depend on $z$? Is it because the size of $\delta$ should only be directly influenced by $\epsilon$ changing?

Comment: That is the definition. $\delta$ can only depend on $\epsilon$. It cannot depend on $z$.  @MichaelCatliMath

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath Note for any given $\epsilon$, the corresponding value you choose for $\delta$ must *be* a constant, so it can of course also depend on other constants like $z_0$. However, if it depends on $z$, then it can't be a constant.